# Cached Network SVG Image

Tags: flutter, image, svg, caching

I want to display an **SVG picture** retrieved **from network** with the help of [Flutter_SVG package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) and use the same picture in different pages with the Hero widget. But each time I use *SvgPicture.network()* widget, it loads the image again and again from network;

**Page 1** & **Page 2**

```
 Hero(
     tag: 'randomTag',
     child: SvgPicture.network(url),
 ),
```

I have tried to combine [Cached Network Image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) dependency with [Flutter_SVG package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) but don't know how to use them as a widget together;

```
Hero(
  tag: 'randomTag',
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: url,
    imageBuilder: (context, ImageProvider<Object> imageProvider) {
      // How to use ImageProvider<Object> with SvgPicture?
    }
  ),
),
```

[svg_cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/svg_cached_network_image) dependency is **not** an option since it is not compatible with other dependencies that I use.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a package called [flutter_img](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_img). It will handle all your network image caching.
here is a demo example for an SVG network image. it will cache this image until you re-run your app

```
  Img(
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shafi-org/portfolio/master/src/assets/flutter-svgrepo-com.svg',
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) to save svg from internet

This line get svg from internet and save it to local, and next time you call it it will get from local

```
var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_cache_manager/latest/flutter_cache_manager/BaseCacheManager/getSingleFile.html

[image]

Comment: Can you detail it little bit please? Because the documentation in that dependency is a little vague.

Comment: I have tried to use .getSingleFile(url) in FutureBuilder<File> widget and it simply crashed the application.

Comment: it work normal for me

Comment: When implementing this dependency with Hero widget it simply doesn't display Hero's animation.